# Route outgoing network traffic via script

Tags: linux, networking, internet, proxy, routing

I need to monitor network activity on the server. I would like all traffic to pass through a script, like a proxy. My proxy script will inspect the request and then serve the response.

How can I do this?

- I'm running Ubuntu, but would be interested in answers for any Linux OS
- The traffic I need to proxy may be on any port (not just port 80)
- This is for outgoing traffic only, not traffic coming into the server.

Comment: Could you be more specific here. Are you trying to do something with the traffic (like block it) or just monitor connections made to your server?

Comment: @MatthewWilliams My script will first inspect the request, if it meets certain criteria it could be logged/blocked. On some occasions the response will also be inspected and may be blocked.

Comment: @MatthewWilliams My script needs to be able to see the request, then fetch the response from the remote server. It can do other things in-between.

Comment: @MatthewWilliams, Sorry I should have mentioned this is for outgoing traffic only. Where the request originates on the server, not a remote.

Comment: I only ask because there are security applications like iptable which can log and block connections for you. Do you have a reason for needing to use your own script or would you be able to use a ready made system (this can apply to outbound traffic also)

Comment: @MatthewWilliams the criteria for logging is quite specific, I don't think another application could do this.

Comment: What sort of criteria do you have?

Comment: @MatthewWilliams Combination of port, remote host name, request body text/keywords. Sometimes the response will also be inspected in a similar way. The details are then logged into a database.